# push data from array to another array in type script or javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, arraylist

i am trying to push data from array to another array in specific form :

first array have this data :

```
array1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 

length even
```

I want to take first 2 in array1 and push in array2.

data in array2 must be :

```
array2: [1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]
```

Comment: It's confusing, neither the input nor the desired output is valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like the following:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  array2 = [];
var i, j, temparray, chunk = 2;
for (i = 0, j = array1.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
  temparray = array1.slice(i, i + chunk);
  array2.push(temparray)
}

console.log(array2)
```